# Logout File PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, logging, logout

I'm making user activity logging, when I log in user login, have successfully entered database, but when I record user exit activity, user name is not recorded in the database. this my code.

```
<?php
include '../koneksi.php';
session_start();
$idPengguna = $_SESSION['username'];
$aktifitas = 'Logout';
$tgl = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
mysql_query("INSERT INTO logfile (nik,aktifitas,tgl_aktif) VALUES ('$idPengguna','$aktifitas','$tgl')")or die(mysql_error());
session_destroy();
header("location:../index.php");
?>
```

[image]

Comment: show us how you connect to your database, you should also consider switching to MySQLi.

Comment: Use session_start(); at the top of your file above include.

Comment: first check echo $idPengguna = $_SESSION['username']; die;

Comment: if it comes then it will be surely added and then session_destroy will work. I think you can debut it yourself very easily.

Comment: If you're writing new code, **_please_ don't use the `mysql_*` functions**. They are old and broken, were deprecated in PHP 5.5 (which is so old it no longer even receives security updates), and completely removed in PHP 7. Use [`PDO`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli_*`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) with _prepared statements_ and _parameter binding_ instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/354577 for details.

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the session variable is working fine and then use this code to insert

```
$servername="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $db="login";//database name
    //connection
    $conn=new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$db);
    //fetch from form

    $sql=$conn->query("INSERT INTO logfile (nik,aktifitas,tgl_aktif) VALUES ('$idPengguna','$aktifitas','$tgl')");

    }
```